# Transform XML to CSV using XSLT in Webservice

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0, xslt, csv, xmldocument

I've searched for this problem but no answer that could help me solve my problem was found.

I am trying to convert an XML file to different file formats using XSLT, e.g., I'm trying to convert an XML to KML and CSV for instance.

I have a webservice (.NET 4.0 in IIS8) which returns a XmlDocument. If I transform my XML to a KML and return it, it works well and returns no error, it returns a valid KML file that works well on Google Earth for instance.

But if I try to convert the XML to a CSV file, I get the following error:

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 40.

I've searched for ways to solve this issue but no luck.

The XML I'm transforming is the following:

```
<experience xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://start.isel.pt:5004/schemas/xsd/experience.xsd">
<data>
<timestamp>2013-05-27 19:37:57</timestamp>
<provider origin="gps">
  <latitude>38.757893</latitude>
  <longitude>-9.275355</longitude>
  <altitude>231.1</altitude>
  <bearing>261.5</bearing>
  <speed>1.5811388</speed>
</provider>
</data>
<data>
<timestamp>2013-05-27 19:38:00</timestamp>
<provider origin="gps">
  <latitude>38.757923</latitude>
  <longitude>-9.275422</longitude>
  <altitude>251.0</altitude>
  <bearing>290.1</bearing>
  <speed>1.4142135</speed>
</provider>
</data>
<data>
<timestamp>2013-05-27 19:38:27</timestamp>
<provider origin="gps">
  <latitude>38.758038</latitude>
  <longitude>-9.275657</longitude>
  <altitude>243.4</altitude>
  <bearing>320.7</bearing>
  <speed>1.0</speed>
</provider>
</data>
<data>
<timestamp>2013-05-27 19:38:30</timestamp>
<provider origin="gps">
  <latitude>38.758007</latitude>
  <longitude>-9.275769</longitude>
  <altitude>240.9</altitude>
  <bearing>301.7</bearing>
  <speed>0.75</speed>
</provider>
</data>
</experience>
```

The XSLTs I'm using are the following:
**XML > KML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <kml>
    <Document>
        <xsl:for-each select="xs:experience/xs:data/xs:provider">
            <Placemark>
                <name><xsl:value-of select="../xs:timestamp"/></name>
                <description>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                        <b>Altitude: </b><xsl:value-of select="xs:altitude"/> m
                        <b>Bearing: </b><xsl:value-of select="xs:bearing"/> o
                        <b>Speed: </b><xsl:value-of select="xs:speed"/> km/h
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
                </description>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates><xsl:value-of select="xs:longitude"/>,<xsl:value-of select="xs:latitude"/>,<xsl:value-of select="xs:altitude"/></coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Document>
</kml>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you try the above two in the following website [XSLT Transformation Online](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php) (for transforming) [Display KML Online](http://display-kml.appspot.com/) (for displaying) everything works well.

**XML > CSV**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <csv>timestamp,origin,reading0,reading1,reading2,reading3,reading4<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="xs:experience/xs:data">
        <xsl:value-of select="./xs:timestamp"/>,<xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./xs:sensor"><xsl:value-of select="./xs:sensor/@origin"/>,<xsl:for-each select="./xs:sensor/*"><xsl:value-of select="."/>,</xsl:for-each><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="./xs:provider/@origin"/>,<xsl:for-each select="./xs:provider/*"><xsl:value-of select="."/>,</xsl:for-each><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </csv>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT with the XML shown above in the website [XSLT Transformation Online](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php) works well, but with the following C# code gives me the error I talked about in the beggining of my post.

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 40.

Am I missing something here? I think I am, but I can't find out where.

**C# Code**

```
public static String ApplyXslt2Xml(String inputXml, String inputXslt)
{
    if (inputXml == null || inputXslt == null) return null;

    XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXslt)))
    {
            transform.Load(reader);
    }

    StringWriter results = new StringWriter();
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXml)))
    {
            transform.Transform(reader, null, results);
    }

    return results.ToString();
}
```

Sorry for all this code, but I wanted to explain as much as I can of the situation I'm facing since I'm trying to solve this issue for some days now.

Many thanks in advance for any helpful suggestions I can get.

Comment: Your code snippet should work. (Beside of the superfluous comma). Which line is trowing this error. Looks like somewhere your cvs string is tried interpreted as XML.

Comment: @hr_117 would it be because my webservice method signature is the following?
`public XmlDocument ExportFile(int fileCode, string fileFormat)`
Because of this I'm creating a XmlDocument and passing my csv string by calling the method LoadXml, as in:

`XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(csvString);`

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma showing up in your csv output for every line. You need to add a test to not add this extra comma at the end like `<xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">,</xsl:if>` within the provider for-each.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <csv>timestamp,origin,reading0,reading1,reading2,reading3,reading4<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="xs:experience/xs:data">
        <xsl:value-of select="./xs:timestamp"/>,<xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./xs:sensor"><xsl:value-of select="./xs:sensor/@origin"/>,<xsl:for-each select="./xs:sensor/*"><xsl:value-of select="."/>,</xsl:for-each><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="./xs:provider/@origin"/>,<xsl:for-each select="./xs:provider/*"><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">,</xsl:if></xsl:for-each><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </csv>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You might also want to consider breaking this into multiple templates instead of for each loops as you could reuse code better.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your comments:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); xmlDoc.LoadXml(csvString);
```

The problem seems to be, that you try to load your cvs text string as an XML data.
Your xslt seems to be indent to create cvs-string inside a XML-element `<cvs>`.

```
<csv>timestamp,origin,reading0,reading1,reading2,reading3,reading4<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
```

But the `<cvs>`-tag does not appear in output because the output method is `text`.

Therefore you have:
To handle the "cvsstring" as string and **not** as XML.
Or change the output method to:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
```

What to do with the `<cvs>`-tag depends on the rest of your solution.

Comment: It's csv, not cvs, but I understood :) Actually I want to return a string response.
And even without the <csv> tag and returning a String it keeps giving me an error.

Comment: Sic sure csv :-(. But loading a string which is not well formed XML with  LoadXml() will not work.